# Loop through JSON data in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, loops

I have a php script returning JSON encoded data like below:

```
         {
            "1":
                {
                    "from":"Vimbai Jongwe",
                    "msg":"wadii"
                },
            "2":
                {
                    "from":"Brian Dube",
                    "msg":"Eh Chibaba"
                }
            }
```

So now i want to access that data using the keys `from` and `msg` to be displayed somewhere.

Comment: you have to loop over this json to display it

Comment: Use `JSON.parse()` and work with it like with any regular javascript object.

Comment: @walk Can you show me

Comment: @kingraphaII `var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(yourJSONstring)`, parsedJSON will be an object corresponding to your JSON text.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop it like below

```js
var data = {
    "1":
        {
            "from":"Vimbai Jongwe",
            "msg":"wadii"
        },
    "2":
        {
            "from":"Brian Dube",
            "msg":"Eh Chibaba"
        }
 }

for(var d in data){
   console.log(data[d].from +"->"+data[d].msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code you can loop and print as in below code

```
a = {
        "1":
        {
            "from":"Vimbai Jongwe",
            "msg":"wadii"
        },
        "2":
        {
            "from":"Brian Dube",
            "msg":"Eh Chibaba"
        }
    };

    for(var i in a){
        console.log(a[i].from);
        console.log(a[i].msg);
    }
```